unable to disbale an form field in angular 14 reactive forms
I am trying to make certain form fields read-only exactly for my users, I am using reactive forms in the angular 14 version.
I want to bind a value but the user shouldn't interact with the form field. I have tried to disable the control after setting the value but it's not working as expected.
 control?.setValue(value);
       control?.disable({ emitEvent: false });


When using reactive forms, you need to use the method disable instead
const control = this.formGroup.get('someControlName');
control.disable();
control.updateValueAndValidity();

You can also disable a form control on initialization using
this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
    someControlName: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}),
});

OR
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    someControlName: [{ value: '', disabled: true }],
});

The [disabled] attribute method should be used only for template driven forms ([(ngModel)] Type)

@sreeK yes that might be the case, try commenting the disable methods one by one and checking until you find the problem, if you provide a stackblitz with the issue reproduced I'll help with debugging

control?.setValue(metadataValue);
status is valid and i can edit the Form controls on UI  ?

@sreeK set value does not enable the control, just comment out the code parts to identify the culprit code!

thanks for support @Naren Murali , was able to resolve the issue
